# Address bar populates with strange address when opening the browser

Tags: browser

When opening the browser both internet explorer and chrome, the address bar populates with an address bar called www.qo-uk.com which was not set by me, though I set my home page as google. Though it shows www.qo-uk.com in the address bar, it shows google in the body of the page.

I doubt is someone hacking my system or is it a virus?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

Your browsers are being hijacked by some sort of malware.

1. Run a [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/thankyou/) scan and remove any malware it detects on your system
2. Manually change the home page in Internet Explorer and Chrome back to your desired default
3. Close and open both browsers a few times, until you are satisfied that the browser hijacker has been completely removed and your desired home page loads 100% of the time